# T-SQL adjacent field from Top or MAX date

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, max

Can anyone help with this T-SQL request?

I have a table of 1000s of orders. Many are repeat orders for the same customer.
I'm trying to create a query that would show many spend habits of each customer, and also the promotional code used on their first ever order. I can pick out their
first order date by using Top or Max function, but how would i return just Cust and first Promotion code from table below?:

```
Cust    Order   Order Date  Promotion Code
JB001   df445   01/02/2014  Web32
JB001   56456   01/02/2015  Cat85
JB001   5646a   03/04/2012  Email22
JB001   ff55f   25/04/2003  Cat67
JB002   45454   28/09/2011  Cat55
JB002   65488   22/10/2011  Email31
JB002   793gg   15/05/2007  Email22
JB003   5444h   10/10/2014  Web14
JB003   gbnm2   22/10/2014  Autumn21
```

to give this?:

```
Cust    Promotion Code
JB001   Cat67
JB002   Email22
JB003   Web14
```

Many thanks in advance,

John

Answer (score 1):

Use `Window Function`

```
SELECT cust,[promotion code]
FROM   (SELECT cust,
               [promotion code],
               Row_number()
                 OVER(
                   partition BY cust
                   ORDER BY [order date]) rn
        FROM   tablename)a
WHERE  rn = 1
```

or use `aggregate` with `Group by` to find the min date per cust then join the result back to main table

```
SELECT cust,
       [promotion code]
FROM   tablename a
       JOIN(SELECT Min([order date]) or_date,
                   cust
            FROM   tablename group by cust) b
         ON a.cust = b.cust
            AND a.[order date] = b.or_date
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `row_number()` to get the first order for each customer:

```
select cust, promotioncode, orderdate
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by cust order by orderdate) as seqnum
      from orders t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Window functions. Like, Max over date, partition by Cust order by rank and selecting records with rank 1.

```
Select Cust,PromotionCode from
 (Select Cust, PromotionCode, 
    Rank () over (partition by cust order by date)
    as rank from records )a
where a.rank=1
```